# Run nodejs published server on client side using c# application

Tags: c#, node.js

I have the following case :

I want to install and run nodejs service on client machine using C# application but I didn't find any possible solution for that so I can't post any code here.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the `Process` class in `System.Diagnostics`. You can use it to launch other applications.

Comment: I think you need nodejs to be installed on client machine to implement this approach. I found many similar solutions but adding nodejs.exe in the process file name !!

Comment: Well, yeah...you'd need NodeJs installed to run a NodeJs service. There's nothing to stop you packaging that with (or bundled into) your application executable.